# Building 64 bit web application on 32 bit build server

Tags: msbuild, 32bit-64bit

we have a cc.net build server on a win 2003 32 bit server. We're building our web projects with `Targets="ResolveReferences;_WPPCopyWebApplication"`. We're deploying the results to a 64-bit web server. The problem is that `_WPPCopyWebApplication` seems to add some system dlls (System.Data, PresentationCore, System.Web) to the /bin-output folder, which breaks on our 64 bit server, since the dlls are 32 bit. We're building with AnyCPU-option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you try to run your web server on 64 bit platform .net uses optimized for x64 system assemblies. therefore your web server crashes. I may be wrong in detailes, but the error in mixing platforms (x86/x64).

I can suggest to compile on your 32 bit build machine with configuration x86. then x64 server will have to use only 32 bit dlls. When your build machine will be migrated to x64, you can  set projects back to AnyCPU.

Comment: Yep, that's one solution, but we'd like to run our web servers on 64 bit only so that we can fully use their ram.

Comment: I know several cases when 32 bit build tools relies on 32 bit dlls. You can find what exactly caused the error, but I think you cann't solve it on 32 bit build server. May be it's time to move on 64-bit build server.